# WordPress Plugin Event Call Before Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, events, plugins, shortcode

I am writing a plugin and I am having some difficulty with when to trigger specific functions of the plugin code.

```
/*
// Plugin information goes here
*/


// ***** Area A

$GLOBALS['example_class'] = new example_class;

class example_class {

    // ***** Area B

    public function admin_init() {
        add_menu_page(

            // ...

        );
    } // End of admin_init function
} // End of example class

add_action('init', function() {
    global $example_class;

    // ***** Area C

    if ( ?????? ) {

        // Sanitize and set the view role
        $view = ( isset( $_REQUEST['view'] ) ) ? sanitize_key( $_REQUEST['ex'] ) : 'get_all';
        // Manage submitted data
        switch ( $view ) {

            // ...

        } // End of switch for view

        // Sanitize and set the action role
        $action = ( isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) ? sanitize_key( $_REQUEST['action'] ) : NULL;
        // Manage submitted data
        switch ( $action ) {

            //...

        } // End of switch for action

    } // End of if page is being shown
});

add_action( 'admin_menu', function() {
    global $example_class;
    $example_class->admin_init();
});

add_shortcode( 'show_public_random', function () {
    global $example_class;
    // ...
});
```

As per suggested [in a previous post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117458/shortcode-i-need-to-throw-a-message-or-load-a-different-page) on stackexchange, I separated the controller side of my plugin into a function called by the `init` event. However, I do not want the code contained in the `init` event function to be evaluated at every page load - I want my code to be evaluated only when the page containing the shortcode is loaded.

I have tried loading a boolean class variable that initializes as false but is changed to true from within the add_shortcode function, but by that time, it's too late - the `init` event has fired, and the function's contents is not run.

Please help me - which expression should I use in Area C of my code? What should I test against to ensure the `init` event function is run only when the shortcode is being used?

Comment: what do you want to check ?

Comment: `init`means first thing that gonna be executed, none of your conditions gonna work before that .. you should probably try hooking your function with other apt hook

Comment: I need to run the conditionals based on action and view to decide what to show on the page, so the apt hook I choose needs to be before the shortcode is called.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer, although messy.

```
/*
// Plugin information goes here
*/
$GLOBALS['example_class'] = new example_class;

class example_class {

    var $public_loaded = false,
        $content = '';

    public function admin_init() {
        add_menu_page(
            // ...
        );
    } // End of admin_init function

    public function get_random( ) {
        // ...
    }
} // End of example class

add_action('init', function() {
    global $example_class;

    // ***** Area A
    // Check for arbitrary variable sent with every user interaction
    if ( if ( isset( sanitize_key( $_REQUEST['tni'] ) ) ) {

        // ***** Area B
        /* Set the class variable `public_loaded` to true after it's
         * clear we're loading a public page which uses our plugin */
        $example_class->public_loaded = true;

        // Sanitize and set the action role
        $action = ( isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) ? sanitize_key( $_REQUEST['action'] ) : NULL;
        // Manage submitted data
        switch ( $action ) {
            // ...
        } // End of switch for action

        // Sanitize and set the view role
        $view = ( isset( $_REQUEST['view'] ) ) ? sanitize_key( $_REQUEST['ex'] ) : 'get_all';
        // Manage submitted data
        switch ( $view ) {
            // ... Generate content and store in $this->content
        } // End of switch for view
    } // End of if page is being shown
});

add_action( 'admin_menu', function() {
    global $example_class;
    $example_class->admin_init();
});

add_shortcode( 'show_public_random', function () {
    global $example_class;
    // ***** Area C
    /* Check to see if page has loaded using the telltale sign
     * If not, load a default view - a random post */
    if ( $example_class->public_loaded === false ) {
        $example_class->content = $example_class->get_random();
        // ...
    }

    // Return the generated content
    return $example_class->content;
});
```

In Area A I've set a qualifying statement to see if a user submitted a variable along with their interaction with my plugin. If the plugin is mine, the code is evaluated, and `action` and `view` modes are evaluated. As well, the function will set the class variable `public_loaded` to true.

In Area C I've set a qualifying statement to see if the class variable has been set to true; if not, a default view is set for the shortcode.